# Prevent Windows 10 from restarting during important events

Tags: windows-10, windows-update

I have a series of important and time sensitive video conferences at odd hours (business hours in Asia) that I absolutely must have my Windows 10 computer working for.  Is there a way to insure that my Windows 10 system will not try to update during or just before these very important events?

Comment: On Version 1607 schedule your updates outside of those hours, on Windows 10, Windows updates cannot be disabled unless WSUS is used

Comment: Windows will not reboot the system if it is actively used. If you stop using it for some reason, check on the Settings app/Updates and security (whatever the name in English is) and see if one update is scheduled. If not, good. If it is there, set manually the time of the following reboot. You can also choose the day.